# predict() with arbitrary coefficients in r

Tags: r, glm, predict

I've got some coefficients for a logit model set by a non-r user. I'd like to import those coefficients into r and generate some goodness of fit estimates on the same dataset (ROC and confusion matrix) vs my own model. My first thought was to coerce the coefficients into an existing GLM object using something like

> summary(fit)$coefficients[,1] <- y

or

> summary(fit)$coefficients <- x

where y and x are matrices containing the coefficients I'm trying to use to predict and fit is a previously created dummy glm object fit to the dataset. Of course, this gives me only errors.

Is there any way to pass an arbitrary coefficient vector to the predict() function or to specify coefficients in a model? Can I somehow force this by passing a vector into the offset argument in GLM? Thanks

Edit: As mentioned in the comments, there's not much statistical basis for using the arbitrary coefficients. I have a business partner who believes he/she 'knows' the right coefficients and I'm trying to quantify the loss of predictive power based on those estimates versus the coefficients generated by a proper model.

Edit2: Per BondedDust's answer, I was able to coerce the coefficients, however wasn't able to clear the error messages that predict() returned due to the coercion, it would appear that predict.lm, which is called by predict, also looks at the rank of the coefficients and that is causing the error.

Comment: In response to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112860/manually-build-logistic-regression-model-for-prediction-in-r/24113738#24113738) I made a [makeglm()](https://gist.github.com/MrFlick/ae299d8f3760f02de6bf) function that sounds like it would be useful in this scenario. If you perhaps provided a more concrete sample, we might be able to try it out.

Comment: @Stencill 
Can you just calculate the predicted values manually by multiplying the relevant variables in your data by coefficients given to you? For example, `coefVector %*% t(cbind(1, dataVariables))`. (Where coefVector is the provided vector of coefficients and datavariables is your data for the relevant coefficients)

Comment: @BondedDust Sorry, was away from the pc for the weekend -- I'll keep to timely updates from now on.

Comment: @user20650 That would seem like the easiest solution. However, I would need to convert a number of factors into dummy variables.

Comment: That's right - `model.matrix` would make this straight forward.

Answer (score 5):

If you follow the code through `predict.glm` which passes the object to `predict.lm`, it appears that the node of the model list that needs to be altered is indeed `fit$coefficients`. However, altering the `summary()`-object will have no effect. The `[['coefficients']]` in the glm and lm objects are not matrices with columns: 'Estimate', 'Std. Error',  't value', 'Pr(>|t|)' such as produced by `summary`, but rather just a vector of coefficients.

```
 fit$coefficients <- y
 newpred <- predict(fit)
```

You might make a copy and work on it if you will need any further use of `fit`.

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot. It's a bit of a hack, since the rest of the glm object (Pvalues, etc.) is now mismatched, but I was able to pass this through predict() successfully.

Comment: Scratch that, it seems I was passing fit incorrectly into predict. >pred <- predict(fit, newdata = sample1)
Where fit is my glm object containing modified coefficients returns the following error:
>Error in `[.data.frame`(beta, piv) : undefined columns selected
In addition: Warning message:
In predict.lm(object, newdata, se.fit, scale = 1, type = ifelse(type ==  :
  prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading

Comment: It was definitely a hack, but that was definitely what you asked for. The method you were using had no real statistical basis. I have no idea where you are in addressing this. You should have A) posted a data example in the first place, and B) updated your question using the edit process rather than posting a comment to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is not an answer to your posted question - which BondedDust answered - but describes an alternate way in calculating the predicted probabilities yourself which might help in this case.

```
# Use the mtcars dataset for a minimum worked example
data(mtcars)

# Run a logistic regression and get predictions 
mod <- glm(vs ~ mpg + factor(gear) + factor(am), mtcars, family="binomial")
p1 <- predict(mod, type="response")

# Calculate predicted probabilities manually
m <- model.matrix(~ mpg + factor(gear) + factor(am), mtcars)[,]
p2 <- coef(mod) %*% t(m)
p2 <- plogis(p2)

all(p1 == p2)
#identical(as.numeric(p1), as.numeric(p2))
```

You can replace `coef(mod)` with the vector of coefficients given to you. `model.matrix` will generate the dummy variables required for the calculation - check that the ordering is the same as that of the coefficient vector.

Comment: How would I change the above (i.e. `plogis(p2)`) if I wanted to predict based on a probit model (i.e. `family = binomial(link = "probit")` in the `glm` command)?

Comment: @rp1 ; I'm not sure - what is the formula for the probit link? ( as `plogis` == `1/(1+e(-xb))` ). I *think* you will use the `pnorm` function (`pnorm(p2)`) but probably best to ask at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: @rp1 ; ok just ran through the example, changing the link to probit : `family=binomial("probit")` , and `p2 <- pnorm(p2)` , then `all.equal(p1, as.numeric(p2), check.attributes = FALSE)` , so seems `pnorm` is the way to go

Comment: @user20650: Thank you so much. I ran some tests too and can confirm that `p2 <- pnorm(p2)` is the correct way to do it. Thanks for your quick reply!

Answer (score 3):

Or, you can use something like this:

> fit <- lm(Y ~ A + B + C, data=fakedata)
>
> fit$coefficients <- c(1, 2, 3) # this would change the coefficients for A, B, C to 1, 2 and 3, respectively.
>
> Y_hat_new <- predict(fit, new_fakedata) # this Y_hat_new will be calculated as your new predicted outcome given the new coefficients and/or new_fakedata.

The results should be the same if you follow the model.matrix route.